# Linear operator norm equality

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $A:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ be a linear operator.
How can I show this equality in the operator norm?

$$\sup_{x\in \mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}} \frac{||Ax||}{||x||} = \max_{x\in \mathbb R^n , ||x||=1}||Ax||$$

I've tried to use the fact that for every $x\in \mathbb R^n$ we have $\frac{x}{||x||}\in S^{n-1}$, but didn't understand what to do next. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\neq0$, then $\left\|\frac x{\|x\|}\right\|=1$, and therefore$$\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}=\frac1{\|x\|}\|Ax\|=\left\|A\left(\frac x{\|x\|}\right)\right\|\leqslant\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|.$$

On the other hand, if $\|x\|=1$, then$$\|Ax\|=\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}\leqslant\sup_{x\neq0}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}.$$

Comment: shouldn't the first line be with $\max$ instead of $\sup$? and can you please clarify the first equality in the first line? thanks

Comment: On a compact the sup is indeed a max. The first equality follows from linearity of A.

Comment: @Mickey In this context, $\max=\sup$. The first equality comes from $\left\|\frac x{\|x\|}\right\|=\left|\frac1{\|x\|}\right|\|x\|=\frac1{\|x\|}\|x\|=1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks, but I meant the first equality meaning $\frac{||Ax||}{||x||}=A(\frac{x}{||x||})$.  Unfortunately we haven't studied that in our classes so I'm trying to comprehend that by myself.

Comment: @Mickey It made no sense! Is it understandable now?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yep! thanks :)